# Как брать конкретные значения из json?

Tags: python, json

Есть огромный `json`, который отличается по `pair`:

```
{"market":"btce","market_name":"Btc-e.com","pair":"btc_usd","last":"1062","change_24":-3.19,"low_24":"1035.12","high_24":"1121.59","vol":"11004146.82"}
```

Пытался с помощью: `filter(lambda x: x['pair']=='btc_usd', data['last'])`, но оно не подходит для буквенного значения.

Как в данном случае брать конкретные данные для разных `pair` в `json`?

Comment: Что значит *"оно не подходит для буквенного значения"* приведите *минимальный* пример ввода, желаемый вывод и что вместо этого получается. Создайте [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Есть пакет json

```
import json
json.loads('{"market":"btce","market_name":"Btc-e.com","pair":"btc_usd","last":"1062","change_24":-3.19,"low_24":"1035.12","high_24":"1121.59","vol":"11004146.82"}')
```

Далее, вы можете выбрать все значения, которые Вам нужны

Comment: {"market":"btce","market_name":"Btc-e.com","pair":"btc_usd","last":"1062","change_24":-3.19,"low_24":"1035.12","high_24":"1121.59","vol":"11004146.82"},{"market":"btce","market_name":"Btc-e.com","pair":"btc_rur","last":"62915.5","change_24":-1.85,"low_24":"61169.62","high_24":"65340","vol":"22892296.61"}



Как мне вывести отдельно для btc_usd и для btc_rur значения? В этом был вопрос

Comment: Так btc_rur -- это значения. Вы можете перебрать все элементы словаря и выдать нужно значение.

Comment: Элементов словаря более 400. Для каждого мне перебирать как data1[1]['change_24'] до data1[399]['change_24'] ?

Comment: Да. Если этого делать не хочется, что нужно перестроить словарь так, чтобы ключами были нынешние значения. В ином случае можно использовать другие структуры данных. Сколько раз Вам нужно обращаться к словарю?